# AngularJs route making HTTP call to the server when html5Mode is true

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-routing, location-provider

I have set html5Mode to `true` in my application. I have the routes defined as follows:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider.
            when('/api/', {
                templateUrl: '../../html/console.html',
                controller: 'paramsController'
            }).
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '../../html/timeline.html',
                controller: 'timelineController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

But whenever i do a request as `http://localhost:3000/api` it makes a HTTP call and request goes to the server instead of resolving to my angular routes.

What is that i need to take care here.

I have the following tag added to my main page:

```
<base href="/">
```

Just stating that, in case it changes anything here.
Is there any other configuration required. I am using `node.js` as a server with `express.js`.

Comment: HTML5 mode will ALWAYS make a server request for anything not directly generated by angular; only using hash routing (`#/`) can avoid server calls.  The server must be set up to redirect anything that it isn't meant to handle back to your index.html.  Requests from angular within the same browser session can avoid the server call by leveraging HTML5 push state, but requests from other sources aren't usually going to use push state to get to your angular app.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you are hitting a URL on which your  front-end application is not being served and the server is not properly configured.

You actually need URL rewriting on the server for that to work.

See the explanation on the angularJS official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side).

Answer (score 1):

As @oLeduc mentioned in his comment, this was caused because of URL rewriting not being configured at the server side.

I added the following in the server side routes(i am using expressjs).

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Server re-writing for angular routing");
    res.sendfile('home.html');
});
```

This enables the routes to be redirected back to angular routes configured for `home.html`.

One can change the pattern from:

```
'/*' to '/api/*`
```

in case you want to match UI route say `/api/test`

Comment: is `home.html` actually the entire HTML which is sent in normal request?